# Eclipse Add Unimplemented Methods with 'default' Methods

Tags: java, eclipse

When using the 'Add unimplemented Methods' quick fix in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, Eclipse automatically adds stub methods that don't technically need to be overridden. These methods include methods whose behavior is already implemented in a super-interface using Java 8's `default` methods. This is a pity, because I either have to manually override the methods or delete the stub methods that are `default` in a super-interface.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps, you could try using a suppress-warnings annotation (if it works).

Comment: Or file a bug to Eclipse devs ?

Comment: when you say super interface do you mean abstract parent classes? AFAIK interfaces cannot have implementations.. and the classes that follow that interface have to actually hold the implementations. interesting.

Comment: I can not reproduce this using Eclipse 4.4.0 (original Luna release) and JDK 8 on Windows 7. I create an interface with 2 methods, one of them with a default body. I then create a class that implements the interface but with no method bodies. When I "Add Unimplemetned Methods" I only get the non-default interface method generated.

Comment: Yes, interfaces. Java 8 introduced `default` methods that allow implementation code in interfaces.

Interestingly, it seems to be pretty random, as it only happens *sometimes*  for me too.

Comment: Though bug [409520](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409520) shows this as fixed in Eclipse JDT 4.3, apparently under some circumstances stubs are still created for default methods.